# Tor Browser crashes at startup

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am on Trisquel 8.0 and I can't get Tor Browser 9.0.1 running. I've installed it a couple time and it still crashes on startup.

Not sure how to get a crash report so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you see when you start it from the command line?

Comment: @JSEvans When I run the command "./Browser/start-tor-browser.desktop" this is what I get in return:

Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach' ...

Then nothing else and the browser does not open

Comment: First, the .desktop file is just a file that links to the actual program. It is not the program itself.  Run Tor Browser directly so you can see the output. You can open that file to see where it it actually running Tor Browser from.


Secondly, after you run it, if nothing happens, run:
"ps -ef | grep -i tor" to see if anything is running in the background

Finally, did it work previously and then stop working after an update?